# How to mark a checkbox as selected in flutter?

Tags: flutter, checkbox

I have an array of checkboxes, I need to highlight ONLY the selected checkbox. However, when I select one it highlights all the checkboxes as selected. How can I correct this? This is what I have done so far:

```js
bool isSelected = false;
var estateRooms = [];

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  final EstateSearch estate =
    ModalRoute.of(context) !.settings.arguments as EstateSearch;

  estateRooms = estate.rooms!;

  super.didChangeDependencies();
}

Expanded(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      for (var item in estateRooms)
        CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text('${item.name}'.toUpperCase()),
          value: isSelected,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              isSelected = value!;
              _roomController.text = '${item.id}';
              print('${_roomController.text}');
            });
          },
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

From the screenshot below, I selected the first checkbox but it marks both the checkboxes as selected.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Many way you can solve this.you need reference checkbox state not only name.you used single ischecked field.to solve you can add ischecked field in your estateRooms model class.or create ischecked array and update the value based on the index

Look this part

```
var estateRooms = [
  EstateRoom(false, "Double Suite"),
  EstateRoom(false, "Family suite")
];
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // bool isSelected = false;
    // var estateRooms = [];

    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      // final EstateSearch estate =
      //     ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as EstateSearch;
      //
      // estateRooms = estate.rooms!;

      super.didChangeDependencies();
    }

    var isSelected = [false, false];

    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var item in estateRooms)
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text('${item.name}'.toUpperCase()),
            value: item.isSelected,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                item.isSelected = value!;
                // _roomController.text = '${item.id}';
                // print('${_roomController.text}');
              });
            },
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class EstateRoom {
  bool isSelected;
  String name;

  EstateRoom(this.isSelected, this.name);
}
```

**OR**

```
var isSelected = [false, false];
var estateRooms = ["Double Suite", "Family suite"];

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // bool isSelected = false;
    // var estateRooms = [];

    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      // final EstateSearch estate =
      //     ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as EstateSearch;
      //
      // estateRooms = estate.rooms!;

      super.didChangeDependencies();
    }

 

    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var item in estateRooms)
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text('${item}'.toUpperCase()),
            value: isSelected[estateRooms.indexOf(item)],
            onChanged: (value) {
              var indexOf = estateRooms.indexOf(item);
              setState(() {
                isSelected[indexOf] = value!;
                // _roomController.text = '${item.id}';
                // print('${_roomController.text}');
              });
            },
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

var estateRooms = [EstateRoom("Double Suite"), EstateRoom("Family suite")];
// var isSelected = [false, false];
// var estateRooms = ["Double Suite", "Family suite"];

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // bool isSelected = false;
    // var estateRooms = [];

    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      // final EstateSearch estate =
      //     ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as EstateSearch;
      //
      // estateRooms = estate.rooms!;

      super.didChangeDependencies();
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var item in estateRooms)
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text('${item.name}'.toUpperCase()),
            value: item.isSelected,
            onChanged: (value) {
              var indexOf = estateRooms.indexOf(item);
              setState(() {
                item.isSelected = value!;
                // _roomController.text = '${item.id}';
                // print('${_roomController.text}');
              });
            },
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class EstateRoom {
  bool isSelected = false;
  String name;

  EstateRoom(this.name, {this.isSelected = false});
}
```

**SampleCode** [Dartpad live check here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=73fae21f6cf4d6948bf084f45f45e9d4)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: Home()),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}
var estateRooms = [
  EstateRoom(false, "Double Suite"),
  EstateRoom(false, "Family suite")
];
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // bool isSelected = false;
    // var estateRooms = [];

    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      // final EstateSearch estate =
      //     ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as EstateSearch;
      //
      // estateRooms = estate.rooms!;

      super.didChangeDependencies();
    }

    var isSelected = [false, false];

    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var item in estateRooms)
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text('${item.name}'.toUpperCase()),
            value: item.isSelected,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                item.isSelected = value!;
                // _roomController.text = '${item.id}';
                // print('${_roomController.text}');
              });
            },
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class EstateRoom {
  bool isSelected;
  String name;

  EstateRoom(this.isSelected, this.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lava,but can't I do this without having to add the "isSelected property" to the estateRoom's object? The reason for this is because the response I get back from the estateRoomsSearch doesn't have the "isSelected" property.

Comment: create a default isSelected property in your model class

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single boolean variable `isSelected`, you need to make a list of boolean variables with the same size of `estateRooms` and assign every item of the list to a different `CheckboxListTile`.

Comment: please how do I do that @tareq albeesh, am very new in flutter?!